# positioning div classes next to another div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

below is my current html layout, inside my `.container` class I have two `<span>` tags with classes of `.download-btn` and `.save-btn`. I want, whenever page load, remove those `<span>` from there and postioning near `<div class="share"></div>`
 tag.

### current layout

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 col-center">
<span class="download-btn">download</span>
<span class="save-btn">save</span>
</div>

<div id="options">
<div class="share"></div>
</div>
```

### expected layout when page load

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 col-center">
</div>

<div id="options">
<span class="download-btn">download</span>
<span class="save-btn">save</span>
<div class="share"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

pls advice how to proceed using js ?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? And what do JavaScript and jQuery have to do with this?

Comment: Why do you not restructure directly your html the way you want it ?

Comment: @j08691 yes using bootstrap. these values a entering by through  a form when user fills. so when it showing on page I want to align it in a positions which I mentioned in expected layout. therefore thought of doing it usng js, but I'm beginner on this. pls advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery,
It can be done in a one line of code.

```js
$("#options").prepend($(".save-btn")).prepend($(".download-btn"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-center">
    <span class="download-btn">download</span>
    <span class="save-btn">save</span>
  </div>

  <div id="options">
    <div class="share"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`prepend()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to move the buttons to the beginning of the element with ID `options`:

```
$('#options').prepend($('.download-btn, .save-btn'));
```

Comment: : thanks, how to find span tags inside container class and prepend the class names like above?

Comment: If you want to move *all* the spans within the container, you could do this:  `$('#options').prepend($('.container span'));`

Answer (score 0):

In this example I'm removing this two buttons from their places, and append them before `<div class="share"></div>` (and I have added content "share" to this `div` to see the difference):

```js
var downloadBtn = $('.download-btn');
var saveBtn = $('.save-btn');

$('.share').before(saveBtn).before(downloadBtn);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 col-center">
<span class="download-btn">download</span>
<span class="save-btn">save</span>
</div>

<div id="options">
<div class="share">share</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RickHitchcock, yes, you're right, thanks for your remark

Answer (score 0):

Use `button` for for the buttons. It's semantically correct and accessible.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var download = $('.download-btn'),
      save = $('.save-btn'),
      options = $('#options');
      
  download.remove();
  save.remove();
  options.prepend(download, save);
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: .1rem solid red;
  min-height: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#options {
  border: .1rem solid blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}

button {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5rem;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-center">
    <button class="download-btn">download</button>
    <button class="save-btn">save</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="options">
  <div class="share"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to `remove()`.  The elements will automatically be moved.